# How to pronounce 'C++' in Spanish

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, pronunciación, informática

I'm doing a presentation in Spanish class, and I'll be mentioning the programming language [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). I'm not sure if it should be pronounced the same way as in English, or if there's a different way to phrase it. How should I pronounce it?

Comment: I tend to hear as much *C más más* as I do *C plus plus* (pronounced with Spanish Us).  I think @Charlie works more in programming and can confirm or say otherwise, but I believe it just depends on the person more than anything else.

Comment: Sería interesante ampliar la pregunta a "C#" (no creo que merezca la pena hacer una pregunta propia para algo que es tan similar). Ahí yo creo que sí que he oído "ce sharp", "ce sostenido" y la voz inglesa.

Comment: @guifa yo personalmente digo "ce más más", y pocas veces he oído otra cosa. En cambio para C# soy de los pocos (o el único) que dice "ce almohadilla". Aunque en realidad debería decir "ce sostenido".

Comment: This is a great question! 
I'm a programmer and regularly speak Spanish (family and friends, but it's not my first language). Though I never if the way I pronounce names of technology should change as well!

Comment: @Diego I'm probably an isolated case, however I prefer calling c# "ce numeral", I would change to call it english (ce sharp) in any format setting because that is what the standard says

Comment: Yo digo "C", pero dejando luego una pausa para que quede claro que hay dos caracteres que no tienen pronunciación, tipo "C&nbsp;&nbsp;   es un gran lenguaje".(Nota: quizás no estoy siendo completamente sincero) :-p

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I checked a few videos on YouTube:

- [1. Programación en C++ || Primer programa en C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld4nzao5XAc): "Ce más más"
- [Aprende a Programar desde cero en C/C++ [Parte 1] (Primer Programa)](https://youtu.be/nqJPIC5V4-g?t=79): "Ce más más"
- [Programación de Juegos C++ - Parte 1: Introducción](https://youtu.be/X6lMTEIzjys?t=15): "Ce más más"
- [Programación de juegos - Snake en c++ #1 (Tutoriales Español y HD)](https://youtu.be/gwfkWpjORRw?t=41): "Ce más más"
- [Guía para programar en CUALQUIER lenguaje | Parte 1/2 (C, C++, Java, Python, PHP, JavaScript, C#...)](https://youtu.be/Laqz6W2ONBI?t=13): "Ce plus plus"
- [Aprender a programar con C++: Ejercicio 1](https://youtu.be/z1hQA3K5FKE?t=137): "Ce más más"
- [Curso Visual C++ | Hola Mundo !! | PARTE 1 | Visual Studio](https://youtu.be/dhAsTvC985g?t=13): "Ce más más"
- [How compile first C++ project on Visual Studio 2015](https://youtu.be/NOL6X18QA9g?t=12): "Ce más más"
- [como programar una calculadora en c++](https://youtu.be/FAle3mB091U?t=25): "Ce más más"
- [Compilar y Depurar C++ en Visual Studio Code](https://youtu.be/kat4-Un93L0?t=16): "Ce más más"
- [Comenzar a programar en C/C++ bajo Linux (IDE, recomendaciones)](https://youtu.be/30vnqE1fXHY?t=4): "Ce más más"
- [Curso Unreal Engine 4 C++ Español | #1 - Instalación e Introducción](https://youtu.be/S-Lf2nQhsCY?t=10): "Ce más más"
- [Como Descargar Dev C++ 5.11 Full Para Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7 | 32bits y 64bits](https://youtu.be/5grPpOZSr_c?t=6): "Ce más más"
- [Programar en Netbeans configuración para C/C++](https://youtu.be/z21aUmt1yig): "Ce más más"
- [Instalación de NetBeans con C, C++ y java](https://youtu.be/ifiAYdgt42g?t=13): "Ce más más"

In this totally non-representative sample, the pronunciation "Ce más más" clearly dominates, whereas "Ce plus plus" is used only once.

Comment: C más más wins, and then you can see "C plús plús" and "C plas plas" haha.

Comment: I think this is representative to actual pronounciation of the name. "Cé más más", followed in the distance by "Cé plús plús", followed in the far end by "Sí plás plás" and "Cé plás plás".

Comment: This reminds me of some Spanish who though that the English name of that good ol' operating system was MS TWO. :)

Answer (score 14):

I'm an engineering informatics student in Perú. The most common pronunciation is "Ce más más", but some teachers also say "Ce pe pe" (from the file extension .cpp), although it is very rare.

We don't say "Si plus plus" like in English that's for sure.

Answer (score 8):

Software engineer from Barcelona, 20 years in the job. If you say C plus plus in English everybody will understand you, it's not usual to say it in Spanish.

For instance, people say Python in English, not 'Pitón' in Spanish.

Technical jargon is very often pronounced in English.

Comment: However, we usually say _radiojed_ instead of _reidiohet_ for Radiohead, for example.

Comment: Often times I hear "páiton"

Comment: También hay quien dice "maincraft" y quien dice "minecrá".

Comment: I believe that is what happens in most languages. People who deal with documentation/videos/colleagues in English tend to pronounce words in English because they are used to do that. However, local pronunciation often wins, sometimes it's also an attempt at English when that person doesn't know English very well. `C#` is another interesting example because many people don't know how to pronounce that in their native language therefore going for "Csharp" is more common.

Comment: @Charlie - ¿Quieres decir maincrá?

Comment: @roof - How is the *th* in Python typically handled?

Comment: @fedorqui - Radiohead is technical language?  // I think *reidiohet* would be the German version!

Comment: @aparente001 Exactly, only German applies Auslautverhärtung everywhere :)

Answer (score 8):

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

---

**Colombia**

- ce más más
- ce plus plus (pronunciando en español la palabra inglesa *plus*)

**Perú**

- ce más más
- ce pe pe

**España**

- ce más más (`/θe mas mas/`)

**Cuba**

- ce maj maj
- ce má má

Answer (score 4):

In Spain, we usually say "ce más más", pronounced /θe mas mas/.

It should be noted that it may be translated and pronounced differently in South America.

Comment: well there is an answer from Peru stating that they also use _ce más más_.

Comment: And an answer from Colombia saying the same

Answer (score 3):

Unlike English speaking people, most Spanish speaking people say "**Ce más más**" rather than "Ce plus plus".

Answer (score 3):

En Colombia por lo común se escucha "**ce más más**" y en ocaciones "**ce plus plus**", pronunciando en español la palabra inglesa "**plus**".

Answer (score 1):

There are already many answers, but I will add mine from a Mexican perspective, I am a computer engineering graduate, and we always call it "ce más más".

Answer (score 1):

En Cuba, como omitimos las S al final de las palabras, o las cambiamos por J...decimos "ce maj maj" o "ce má má".

Answer (score 0):

In Spain, most English brand names are said in English (maybe with a Spanish accent/pronunciation on it if you prefer).

For example, for 'iPhone' you just say it like 'eye-Phone', you don't say 'ee-phone'.  I'm guessing the normal thing would be to say 'C plus plus' as 'C plus plus' and not to translate it into 'Ce más más', as this would sound very strange.

Edit: When I say with Spanish pronunciation, I mean you would say 'C plus plus', but you might put Spanish pronunciation on it as 'c ploohs ploohs'.

Comment: This would make sense, but most of the other answers seem to agree that Ce mas mas is very usual, although either would work. Anyways, I'll be using Ce mas mas

Comment: I've read the other comments and seen as well that 'Ce más más' might be common in other Spanish-speaking countries, but this is a comment above from a software engineer from Spain who says it is not normal use the Spanish translation in Spain, but yes I suppose either will work.  To be honest, I would probably avoid using the English if it was me so as to not break from using Spanish words.

Comment: OK, another comment from someone in Spain saying 'ce más más' is normal.  Maybe the person who insists in saying it in English 'c plus plus' is probably just because they are trying to show off that they know some English or something.

Comment: @Tom - I consider it more likely that that individual happens to work in an environment where English has more sway -- perhaps some influential person there came into a lot of contact with someone who had lived in an English-speaking country.