# How to pronounce 'c#' in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, pronunciación, informática, deletreo

In [How to pronounce 'c++' in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30248/1674) I see some comments there debating how is the language [C#](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp) called in Spanish.

Wikipedia states *si sharp* is the way they pronounce it in English. I have found a thread [[OT] - Como se pronuncia C#, y C++?](https://es.comp.lenguajes.cpp.narkive.com/FkndnRSq/ot-como-se-pronuncia-c-y-c) in a Spanish C++ forum where someone says:

> En cuanto a C# lo que más he oido yo es la pronunciación inglesa, y en cuanto a oírla me refiero a que la gente la usa tambien aquí. Es decir, **C sharp**.

While others jokingly (and remembering that C# is in fact C++++) state:

> Si eso es así, el C# debería ser "**Ce plus plus plus plus**".

And others note that the *#* symbol is called *almohadilla* in Spanish or focus on the musical symbol that sets the note as *sostenido*, and hence state:

> C# es "C Sharp"... En plan coña lo llamamos (efectivamente) "**C almohadilla**" o "**C sostenido**", pero creo que casi todos hemos aceptado el nombre en inglés.

So: what is the common way to say *C#* in spoken Spanish? Does it change depending on the country?

Comment: "Ce plus plus plus plus". Puaaaaaj!!! si el IEEE es el "ay i cubo" o "i e cubo" (I triple E en inglés) C# debería ser en todo caso "Ce plus cuarta". :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked a number of videos on YouTube to find out how C# is pronounced "in the wild". Below are the links (with approximate timestamps in parentheses):

Si sharp:

- José Dimas Luján Castillo: [Diferencias entre C, C++ y C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bI1iHNVw6_o) (14 seconds: "diferencias entre ce, ce más más y si sharp");
- [C# desde cero con Visual Studio [Parte 1] (IDE y Hola mundo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXk8jPNaP_o) (20 seconds into the video);
- [Aprende a Programar C# | Programación Orientada a Objetos con C# desde Visual Studio 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wMaIoqWDOQ) (105 seconds into the video);
- nicosiored: [Tutorial Programación Windows Forms C# 1 --- Creación de un proyecto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AN79L5B7a58) (52 seconds);
- Hermes Mosquera: [Clases, objetos y metodos en C# con Windows Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxsdGjhe8kI) (14 seconds into the video);
- Nekszer: [Tutorial C# - #1 Clases y Métodos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWPp45h2HjA) (7 seconds);
- LearnWtutorials: [Tutorial 2 de C# - Aplicación de consola (Hola mundo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzckUcqwWF0) (9 seconds);
- Platzi: [Por qué aprender C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWBXHBLzUs0) (11 seconds);
- TuProgramaras: [1.- Programar en C#, MessageBox "Hola Mundo"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YxuWyH2q7Y) (11 seconds);
- Programming 2Torials: [Aprende a Programar en C# - Crear Login Parte 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h611IKh--s) (41 seconds);
- n n: [Programando en C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_1rcPAoeCA) (6 seconds; but "se y se más más" for "C & C++");
- Eliezer De León (Dominica): [APRENDIENDO C# (Capítulo I) [Definición, Programación Orientada a Objetos, Variables]](https://youtu.be/Pa3ERUp5MzU) (10 seconds);
- Eduardo Corona: [Video Tutorial - Nivel 1 C# ¿Como Empezar a Programar?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHcyUM5Md94) (36 seconds);
- Danny Feliz: [Como hacer una Calculadora en Visual C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ULtNaT5sCk) (13 seconds);
- hdeleon.net: [Cómo Hacer El RECONOCIMIENTO De VOZ Con C# En Visual Studio | Speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bHRJotJpLA) (9 seconds);
- Alva Majo: [Unity para retrasados](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT7vDqm4xiY) (5 minutes + 7 seconds into the video: "ci sharp"?);
- Gerry Studios: [Guardar y cargar el texto de un RichTextBox. Con C#. Paso a paso.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IGh8Q2sJXY) (15 seconds);
- Diogenes Amaury Martinez: [Crear Menú Y Llamar Formularios en C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zG06vtko_mM) (18 seconds);* Yo Androide: [LIBRO EN ESPAÑOL RECOMENDADO PARA APRENDER A PROGRAMAR EN C# (CSHARP)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biu57Uw1ve0) (12 seconds);
- VerTutoriales: [Curso intensivo C# .Net de menos de 3 horas. Aprende a programar aplicaciones Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QsRMMFVcq0) (10 seconds; "ci sharp?).

Ce sharp:

- Master Devs: [Curso de Programación con C# y Visual Studio desde cero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TBJiRqfpN8) (2 seconds, 8 seconds);
- GioCode: [Como hacer un juego de snake en C# (Windows Forms)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ9Vtcokkb4) (6 seconds; "se sharp"?; 17 seconds);
- Programacion101.net: [C# Orientada a objetos | #0 - Introducción. ¿Qué es una clase? ¿Qué es un objeto?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C95ca4nJHGs) (30 seconds; 56 seconds);
- Hektor Profe: [Introducción al Lenguaje C# para Unity 5 - Tutorial Completo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWkg9XR8gJk) (14 seconds);
- Hector Pulido: [COMO CREAR NUESTRA PRIMERA RED NEURONAL C# - Perceptron simple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSjlvulOiQY) (26 seconds);
- VTInfolance: [#1. Unity 5. Aprende a programar tus juegos con C#.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAZjyzL75aQ) (35 seconds, 40 seconds);
- pablo ramirez: [Curso C# Lección 1.-Crear una aplicación de consola](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XatzJ83HoMA) (6 seconds);
- Tutorials - LeParadoxHD: [Programación C# en Linux - Parte 1: Instalación - MonoDevelop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBxFh0VGc64) (8 seconds, 33 seconds).

"Si sharp" clearly dominates, but "ce sharp" is also rather common. I could not find any examples of "ce plus plus plus plus", "c almohadilla" or "c sostenido".

Comment: Great investigation, thanks a lot! So the English way of saying it clearly dominates.

Answer (score 6):

I'm an engineering informatics student from Peru. So far I've only heard the "C sharp" (as in English) and "Ce sharp" ("Ce" as the letter name in Spanish), being the latter the most common one in my context.

Comment: Is the C pronounced as in English (/siː/) or as the regular Spanish name of the letter (/se/), though? Or is that the difference you’re alluding to when you write “C” and “Ce”?

Comment: Yes, that's the difference I'm alluding when writing "C" and "Ce", sorry for the ambiguity. 
The first "C" is pronounced as in English (/siː/) and "Ce" is pronounced as the letter in Spanish (/se/). Both "sharp"s are pronounced the same (as in English).

Answer (score 6):

I've heard "Ce almohadilla" but I personally use "Ce Sharp", saying C as the spanish letter and "#" as the english word "Sharp". I know, mixing languages is a bad practice but that's what people say in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

Ce Gato/Gatito (as a joke in college/university)

Because of the "gato" or "tres en linea" game.

---

PS. "Gato" means Cat

[image]

Comment: I like this so much better than *almohadilla*.

Comment: Me podría acostumbrar a llamarle así

Comment: Interesantemente, en inglés se llama tic-tac-toe (el juego) y cuando termina en empate se le refiere como un "cat's game" al resultado. Me pregunto si de ahí deriva la referencia a gatito

Answer (score 1):

En Cuba, alguien ajeno a la programación podría decir "Ce numeral", 
sin embargo, entre programadores se usa "Ce sharp" o "Ci sharp".

Answer (score 0):

En mi empresa decimos "Ce sharp" y "Ce más más", aunque algún empleado recien llegado dice "Ce plus plus", al final termina adaptandose al "Ce más más".

Comment: entiendo que digan "Ce mas mas" y "Ci plus plus", pero "Ci mas mas" o "Ce plus plus" suena algo ridiculo xD