# How would one translate "(Video) game developer" to Spanish

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, informática

A bit back I asked about how to pronounce "C++" [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/30248/how-to-pronounce-c-in-spanish/30249#30249), now I need to know something else, game developer. I'm not asking how to pronounce this, but how to translate it. According to [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=developer) developer would be 'desarrollador'
and I already know that 'video game' is 'videojuego' so I would think that game developer (which in most contexts including this one is referring to video games specifically) would be

> desarrollador de videojuegos

but I'm not sure. Is this right or is there a better way to say it?

Comment: Once you have a possible translation, you can check whether it is being used in natural conversations and articles by googling with quotes around the phrase.  Even professional translators do this!

Answer (score 3):

"Desarrollador (de software)" is the right term in Spanish for "(software) developer". Switch back from the Spanish to English version of "[Desarrollador de software](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desarrollador_de_software)" in wikipedia. You can also validate this by searching for "desarrollador de software" on LikendIn or similar sites that post job offers.

"Developer" could have a different translations in different domains (for example, in real state a "developer" would be a "promotor"), but in software the term used is "desarrollador", so a game developer is a "desarrollador de **video**juegos". It may obvious from the content that we are talking about video games and not board games, but you kind of need to keep the "video" in there.